# How to enable System Event Logging

Tags: fusionauth

We are attempting to troubleshoot a problem and think that events logging in FusionAuth could be useful. However no events are being captured on our FusionAuth 1.6.1 installation. Have we missed a configuration step to enable the logging?

Comment: Can you expand on the issue you are looking into? FusionAuth only uses the event log for specific things right now and it could be that your issue is not logged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 1.6.1, the event logging feature is used to capture only a certain number of errors and debug statements. Here are the things that are written to the event log currently:

- Email errors (like a bad template variable or SMTP connection failures)
- Lambda errors (if a Lambda fails at runtime)
- Lambda info messages (written inside the Lambda)
- Lambda debugging (written inside the Lambda)
- SAML handling errors (both IdP and SP errors)
- SAML debugging messages

I believe those are the only messages we write out currently. If your situation is different than those, the errors won't be written out to the event log yet. If you can provide details of your situation, we can probably add the errors to the event log in an upcoming release. Feel free to open a Github Issue for this.

Comment: This is helpful. Our event log is completely empty and we have SMTP and SAML configured. It would be really useful to monitor SSO redirection events. Login failures, user creation (by API) aren't appearing in event or audit log.

Comment: FusionAuth doesn't log API calls to the audit log currently. You can audit all of the calls by calling the `/api/system/audit-log` API though. This is how we do it in our UI actually. When you take an action in the UI, it will call the correct API and then also call the audit log API to record the action.

Comment: Sorry for the slow responses from me. We've upgraded the instance to 1.7.1 and started seeing Event Log entries for email template and OpenIDConnect afterwards.